# Send images to backend using ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I want to make a post request to backend with all form data.
Uploading the images  i get an array with data:

[image]

```js
const normFile = e => {
    const getFileList = e.fileList.map( i => i.originFileObj);

    console.log('Upload event:', getFileList);

    fetch('https:///uploadapi', {
      method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify({ images: getFileList })
    })
      .then(async response => {
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log(data, 'res data')
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('There was an error!', error);
      });

    if (Array.isArray(e)) {
      return e;
    }
    return e && e.fileList;
  };
```

Above is my code where i use Ant Design uploader.

But how to delete the `File` text before each object?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use multipart/form-data header

Let's say you have an input

```
<input type="file" onChange={uploadFile}/>
```

And logical part:

```
uploadFile = (e) => {
     const formData = new FormData();   
     formData.append('name_your_file', e.target.files[0])
     fetch('https:///uploadapi', {
     method: 'POST',
     headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' },
     body: formData
    })
}
```